# Choice of metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions

We have the metric given by a matrix $g_{\mu\nu}$, however, some textbooks define it as:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
And others as:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Is there is a specific physical significance to either one of the choices or is it simply a convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no physical significance. Choose whichever makes your calculation easier.

Of course, if you want to compute something physical like, say, the proper time, you need to put in a negative sign, or not, depending on your choice.